# Dibujar polilíneas múltiples con diferentes colores usando el mapa de Google

Tags: php, google-maps, script

Agradecería me me ayudaran con lo siguiente:
Quiero dibujar la ruta de diferentes colores para esto asigno `strokeColor` de acuerdo un valor en la consulta. Parte del select en mysqli:

```
(CASE WHEN indice<= '300' THEN '#000099'
            WHEN indice> '301' AND indice<= '699' THEN '#009900'
            WHEN indice> '700' AND indice<= '950' THEN '#fff202'
            WHEN indice> '951' THEN '#ce0404' END) as strokeColor
```

En el scritp tengo esto:

```
    var map;
    var pathCoordinates = Array();
    function initMap() {

            var mapLayer = document.getElementById("map-layer"); 
            var centerCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(-17.032187021102644,-70.71385628637512);
            var defaultOptions = { center: centerCoordinates, zoom: 16 }
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.terrain;
            map = new google.maps.Map(mapLayer, defaultOptions);
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            <?php
        if (! empty($data)) {         
            foreach ($data as $point) 
            {
        ?>  
            pathCoordinates.push({lat: <?php echo $point["latitude"]; ?>, lng: <?php echo $point["longitude"]; ?>, strokeColor:'<?php echo $point["strokeColor"]; ?>'});        
            new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: pathCoordinates,
              geodesic: true,                 
              strokeOpacity: 1,
              strokeWeight: 4,
              map: map

        });

                        <?php
            }
        }
        ?>  
    }
```

Lo que hice fue asignar en el `pathCoordinates` la latitud, longitud y color:

```
pathCoordinates.push({lat: <?php echo $point["latitude"]; ?>, lng: <?php echo $point["longitude"]; ?>, strokeColor:'<?php echo $point["strokeColor"]; ?>'});
```

Sin embargo cuando se dibuja la linea es de un solo color. Intente de esta y otras formas, pero el resultado es el mismo.

Gracías

Verónica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El atributo `strokeColor` de un objeto `google.maps.Polyline` es extensivo para toda la polilínea. Si tu quieres pintar cada segmento de diferente color, tendrías que hacer N polilíneas.

En tu caso, quieres pintar 4 segmentos y eso implicaría hacer 4 polilíneas. Lo que puedes hacer es detectar cuando el color sea distinto al anterior, lo que indica que termina un segmento e inicia un segmento nuevo

Primero, metería todo el resultado en la variable de javascript.

```
var datos=null;
<?php
 if (!empty($data)) { 
    echo 'datos = '.json_encode($data).';';
 }
?>
```

Y luego hacer algo como en el ejemplo que sigue:

```js
var datos = [
    {  lng: -1,lat: 1, color: '#A00' },
    {  lng: -2,lat: -1, color: '#A00' },
    {  lng: -3,lat: 1, color: '#A00' },
    {  lng: -4,lat: -1, color: '#A00' },
    {  lng: -5,lat: 2, color: '#A00' },
    {  lng: -6,lat: -2, color: '#A00' },
    {  lng: -7,lat: 1, color: '#A00' },
    {  lng: -8,lat: -1, color: '#A00' },
    {  lng: -9,lat: 2, color: '#A00' },
    {  lng: -10,lat: -2, color: '#0A0' },
    {  lng: -11,lat: 3, color: '#0A0' },
    {  lng: -12,lat: -2, color: '#0A0' },
    {  lng: -13,lat: 1, color: '#0A0' },
    {  lng: -14,lat: -4, color: '#0A0' },
    {  lng: -15,lat: 1, color: '#0A0' },
    {  lng: -16,lat: 3, color: '#0A0' },
    {  lng: -17,lat: 1, color: '#0A0' },
    {  lng: -18,lat: -2, color: '#0A0' },
    {  lng: -19,lat: 3, color: '#00A' },
    {  lng: -20,lat: -2, color: '#00A' },
    {  lng: -21,lat: 2, color: '#00A' },
    {  lng: -22,lat: 2, color: '#00A' },
    {  lng: -23,lat: 3, color: '#00A' },
    {  lng: -24,lat: 4, color: '#00A' },
    {  lng: -25,lat: -1, color: '#00A' },
    {  lng: -26,lat: 2, color: '#00A' },
    {  lng: -27,lat: 1, color: '#00A' },
    {  lng: -28,lat: 2, color: '#00A' },
    {  lng: -29,lat: 2, color: '#00A' },
];

function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: -8, lng: -13}
        });
        var currentColor='#A00',
            path=[];
        datos.forEach(function(punto) {
          if(punto.color!==currentColor) {
            path.push(punto);
            new google.maps.Polyline({
              map:map,
              strokeColor:currentColor,
              path:path
            });
            currentColor=punto.color;
            path=[punto];
          } else {
            path.push(punto);
          }
        });
        new google.maps.Polyline({
              map:map,
              strokeColor:currentColor,
              path:path
        });
            
        
        
      }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {
 height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyBRqo4qwqHHrtbY9aL6vYYDw1GOhkK97MQ"></script>
<div id="map">
```

Nótese que cuando detecto que inicia un nuevo segmento, añado el punto tanto al segmento actual como al próximo, para que los segmentos formen una ruta contínua.

Comment: Funciono perfecto!!

Answer (score 0):

Deberías meter el color en las opciones que tienes debajo:

```
 if (! empty($data)) {         
      foreach ($data as $point) 
      {
       ?>  
        pathCoordinates.push({lat: <?php echo $point["latitude"]; ?>, lng: <?php echo $point["longitude"]; ?>'});        
        new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: pathCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,      
        strokeColor:'<?php echo $point["strokeColor"]; ?>           
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        map: map

       });

 <?php
      }
 }
```

O cambiar strokeColor por `color: <?php echo $point["strokeColor"]; ?>`